# Laravel MondoDB - How to count and groupBy records

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and jenssegers/laravel-mongodb package for MongoDB. I'm trying to do this in MongoDB:

```
$offers = Offer::select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), DB::raw('count(created_at) as cnt'))->groupBy('date')->get();
```

Using example from this url: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/361
I tried this:

```
// in Offer.php
public function scopePostedJobs($query){
        $q = $query->groupBy('created_at');
        $q->getQuery()->aggregate = [ 'function' => 'count', 'columns' => [ 'created_at' ] ];
        return $q;
    }


// in controller
$postedJobs = Offer::postedJobs()->get();
```

This example doesn't work properly since it groups by full timestamp and I only need date, without time. So how can I group by created_at but using only date without time?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @BrentR and @chridam I found this solution:

```
$postedJobs = Offer::raw()->aggregate(array(
                array(
                    '$group' => array(
                        '_id' => array(
                            'yearMonthDay' => array(
                                '$dayOfYear' => '$created_at'
                            )
                        ),
                        'count' => array( '$sum' => 1 )
                    )
                )   
            ));
```

For some reason $dateToString didn't work for me so I used suggestion from @BrentR and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can use mongo aggregation with the $dayOfYear operator to achieve this grouping.

See https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfYear/

Answer (score 1):

For better performance use the underlying MongoDB driver's aggregation framework methods as this uses the native code on the MongoDB server rather than the `.groupBy()` methods which basically wraps mapReduce methods.

Consider the following aggregation operation which uses the date operator 
**[`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/#exp._S_dateToString)** within the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline to convert a date object to a string according to a user-specified format

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "yearMonthDay": { "$dateToString": { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$accesstime" } }
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
]);
```

The equivalent Laravel example implementation:

```
$postedJobs = DB::collection('collectionName')->raw(function($collection)
{
    return $collection->aggregate(array(
        array(
            "$group" => array(
                "_id" => array(
                    "yearMonthDay" => array(
                        "$dateToString" => array( 
                            format => "%Y-%m-%d", 
                            date => "$created_at" 
                        )
                    )
                ),
                "count" => array( "$sum" => 1 )
            )
        )   
    ));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you help but when I execute your code the "$dateToString" is parsed as PHP variable and I get 'not defined' error, if I put single qoutes like this: '$dateToString' then I get this: exception: invalid operator '$dateToString'